# How to mount my Linux partition in Windows 8?

Tags: mount

I am not being able to access the partition which is used by Ubuntu. In fact I don't know how to mount that partition from Windows 8.
Hope folks may help me.

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu is using another filesystem type by default called [ext4](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) (resp. ext2 or ext3) which Windows cannot read by default. You need additional programms like [Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) to display the content of that partition in Windows. The other way around it is much easier because Linux kernel supports Microsofts NTFS by default. If you want to acces your Linux partition under Windows more frequently you might want to consider installing Ubuntu on a NTFS formatted drive.

Comment: There are some other programs you can use. Just google for them. But you cannot read the file system without any additional software.

Comment: Can't I mount it so that I could use as if its a Windows partition?

Comment: no. unfortunately windows has no built in support for that drive. you have to either install Ubuntu on an NTFS drive or use external software.